# Android screen management

Tags: android

This is a very basic question, I have a few screens, now when you go from one to another you can then press back and cycle back through all the windows.

I'd rather that when you pressed back it took you to a specific window for instance:

- Menu Screen
  ---->User clicks Info
- Info Screen
  ---->User clicks Ride Info
- Ride Info
  ---->User clicks back
- Info Screen

Now is this to do with the hierarchical parent, will this define where it goes back to?

The second part of my question is if I don't have any resources to release or information to store for an on-resume what should I do when the user pauses my app? At the moment if you go back to the menu screen and re-select the app it will start a new instance rather than resuming. Do I just simply implement:

```
    @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
}
```

Apologies if this is a bit basic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look in to setting FLAGS for your intent while opening new activity [Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29)

Something like this -

```
Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class);
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no basic questions here :)

Easiest way to do this is to override the onBackPress() function.

Sample :

> @Override
>   public void onBackPressed() {
>       //Do what you want here
>   }

For saving variables when users leave the app, you need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)

> @Override
>   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
>     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
>     bundle.putInt("sample", 1);
>   }

Comment: Sometimes I get questions like this where I feel I must have skipped over an important lesson and feel really basic for having to ask! Thanks for the support. I don't really want to save anything when the user leaves the app. I'd rather the current window was just re-created whenever it is resumed. But what is actually happening is if I minimize and come back via the launcher a new instance of the app is started from the first screen?

Answer (score 1):

For your two parts:

1) It's almost always best to let Android handle the back button, the order of which is determined by the back stack: [see here for an explanation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). If you want hierarchical navigation, I would recommend looking into the `up` button - see [this developer page](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) for a good explanation of how to use the different navigation tools.

Additionally, if you don't want to have an activity appear in your back stack, you can set the attribute `android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest, which will mean that the user can't return to it using the back button.

2) If the user has left your app, it's automatically paused, you don't need to implement `onPause` or `onResume` for this to happen. However, it's also up for collection to be terminated by the OS. If this happens, then it will be restarted when the user opens it from the launcher again. Any previously running instances of the app should automatically be opened.

Comment: The no history thing sounds like the easiest way to do what I want. 

If the onPause and things are called automatically, why when I resume my app via the launcher icon on the menu does it start a new instance and not open the app where I left off like other apps do?

Comment: That must be something that you've put in somewhere, as all of my apps come back automatically. If you post your manifest it may be something in there...

Comment: Link to the manifest: http://pastebin.com/N0Awp3gG

I hope it is an easy fix in the manifest as that would explain why I thought I'd missed out some critical step in my learning.